# Flex 4.6 Mobile - ItemRenderers and application data

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flexbuilder

A question about ItemRenderers: let's say I have an ArrayCollection that is my application data sitting inside a global object. I them populate a sparks list with this data, setting the ArrayCollection as the dataProvider.

So each ItemRenderer gets a copy of an item sitting in the array. You can override the "set data" method to set the data something more domain-specific. The problem is that the data is a copy of the original item.

Now let's say we want to add some data to the item while inside the ItemRender. For example, it could call a method on the item telling it to load some details about itself, or maybe we allow the user to modify something on the item.

Obviously, we can't do any of this if we are operating on a copy because it will be thrown away as soon as the ItemRenderer is destroyed and the original object doesn't know anything about what happened.

So what's the best practice? Should I just use the itemIndex of the renderer to pull out the original item from my global array like this:

{globalArrayCollection}.getItemAt(this.itemIndex)

But it seems kind of clunky to me. Is there a best practice for dealing with this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I'm following but it sounds like you're looking for a way to get at your item renderer to set/change a value.

You could go about accessing a method on the renderer directly.

In your renderer:

```
public function setSomeValue(aValue:String):void{
     someString = aValue;

}
```

You would also set the data on your ArrayCollection as well.

To access this method you would use this:

```
var dataGroup:DataGroup = list.dataGroup;
var itemRenderer:YourItemRenderer = dataGroup.getElementAt(list.selectedIndex) as YourItemRenderer;

itemRenderer.setSomeValue("string");
```

Comment: Yes, you understood the question perfectly and yes, that's the same solution I came up with. But you always have to modify the code in both places. Not an ideal solution, but probably the only one possible. I'll wait a few days to see if someone can offer a better solution, otherwise I'll mark this as answered. Thanks

Comment: You could pass an instance of your ArrayCollection into the setSomeValue method and have that one function update both

Comment: Still, that instance would be a copy of the original data. Same problem. I would like to have just a single copy of the data in one global place, is that too much to ask?  :-)

Comment: The collection you pass into setSomeValue wouldn't be a copy of your original ArrayCollection, it would just be a reference. So yes you would still have to set the data in two places but it could be handled in one method.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, why do you think that original ArrayCollection won't change if you change values in itemRenderer? For me this works and initial ArrayCollection changes.

```
[Bindable]
protected var model:Model;

override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
    super.data = value; 
    this.model = value as Model;
}

protected function changeValue():void
{
    model.value = "newValue";
}
```

Or am I misunderstood something?

Comment: I tried responding with a code example but couldn't get it to format correctly on this site. Anyway, the original ArrayCollection is not modified if you execute the code above. try putting the following trace inside your changeValue method:        trace("BEFORE MODIFICATION:");
    trace("Global variable: "+MyModel.dataList[itemIndex].value);
    trace("Local variable: "+this.model.value);
    
    this.model.value="MODIFIED VALUE";
    
    trace("AFTER MODIFICATION:");
    trace("Global variable: "+MyModel.dataList[itemIndex].value);
    trace("Local variable: "+this.model.value);

Comment: So I didn't understand what you are doing. Did you mean, that you have created class MyModel with static dataList and trying to modify it? Anyway I tried this way and get this results: BEFORE MODIFICATION: Global variable: 1 Local variable: 1 AFTER MODIFICATION: Global variable: 2 Local variable: 2 So binding works perfectly there too